# After upgrading from Magento 2.1 to Magento 2.3.3 getting error at checkout step cart-items.js of getCartLineItemsCount() method

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.3

I am upgraded my Magento V2.1 to Magento V2.3.3 after I'm getting below error in the checkout step.

[image]

With the above error not able to see the Order Summary items in the right sidebar Items in the cart.

Any help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my self by disabling/enabling third-party modules. The third-party module casing error in the checkout step. After disabling it's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have overrided some js files in your modules, that have the structure of 2.1 , try to :

- grep -irH "length" app/ ( will show the js file that include the length )
- compare the file with the new vendor to see what is updated
- Remove the overrides / comment (temporary) the js files / make them
  compatible with the new version .

**(If this fixes the issue , make the override based on 2.3.3).**

- rm -rf var/cache/* generated/* pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/*
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento
  setup:static-content:deploy